# Generic binary Search tree class declaration error

Tags: java, generics, binary-search-tree

I am trying to create a BinarySearchTree using generics, but I am bumping into an error. I want my class to extend Number and Implement Comparable. So I declare it this way:

```
public class BinaryTree<K extends Number implements Comparable<? super K>, E>
```

But I am getting an error.

File: F:\Java\intro-prog-java\bookClasses\Lab_5\BinaryTree.java  [line: 1]
  Error: > expected

I cannot get whats wrong with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the wrong syntax. Try this:

```
public class BinaryTree<K extends Number & Comparable<? super K>, E>
```

This syntax is described in the [Bounded Type Parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html) topic of the Java tutorials on generics as well as [§4.4 of the Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#108850).